# Error- Index is not a b-tree postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

In our production, environment suddenly we recieved error that index is not a btree for one index.After performing reindex on the same, we were able to access the table, But we are unable to get root cause of the issue. Can any one help us??

Comment: Sounds like the field identifying the type of index got corrupted.  What was the exact error message?

Comment: What was the statement that caused that error?

Comment: All the statements fired in db related to that table caused the error. The error was same as the title.

Comment: That is not a Postgres error message. What is the output of `select version();`?

Comment: EnterpriseDB 10.7.15, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit

Comment: Your title will not be generated by any PostgreSQL error message.  If you quote things, quote them exactly and but them in quote marks, so we know the precise beginning and ending.  If you need to elide sensitive information, make it blatantly obvious you have done so.  Similar error messages are generated by amcheck, but you didn't describe using that.